# Looping through an Multidimentinal/Associative Array

Tags: php, arrays, parsing, loops

Looking for some help with looping through a multidimensional/associative array in PHP. Essentially, I need to loop through and output the certain key values in a table.  Not having much luck.

Here is a sample of my array.

```
$myarray = array( 
"body"                   => array(

"0"                      => array( 
  "machine"                 => array(
    "id"                     => "1",
    "name"                   => "macbookpro",
    "description"            => "laptop machine",
    "state"                  => "reserved",
    "state_since"            => "2013-08-28 12:05:00",
    "queue_snapshot"         => array(
      "time"                   => "2013-08-01 12:00:00",
      "jobs"                   => "450",
      "jobs_available"           => "90",
      "cputime_running"        => "00:01:00",
      "cputime_eligible"       => "00:90:00",
      "cputime_block"          => " 90:00:00",
    )
  )
),

"1"                    => array(
  "machine"                 => array(
    "id"                     => "2",
    "name"                   => "ipad",
    "description"            => "tablet machine",
    "state"                  => "available",
    "state_since"            => "2013-08-28 12:05:00", 
    "queue_snapshot"         => array(
      "time"                   => "2013-08-01 12:00:00",
      "jobs"                   => "50",
      "jobs_available"         => "20",
      "cputime_running"        => "00:05:00",
      "cputime_eligible"       => "00:12:00",
      "cputime_block"          => " 00:10:00",
    )
  )
)
));
```

I have some values in this array that will need to be accessed later so I only need to be able to access particular values in order to create this table. Needs to output like this....

Machine Name | Description     | State     | Jobs | Jobs Available |

macbookpro     laptop machine    reserved    450    90

ipad           tablet machine    available   50     20

Answer (score 0):

Untestet on the fly

```
 <?php
      if(isset($myarray['body']) && is_array($myarray['body']))
      foreach($myarray['body'] as $id=>$arr) {
         $name = $arr['name'];
         $description = $arr['description'];
         $jobs = $arr['queue_snapshot']['jobs'];
         $jobs_available = $arr['queue_snapshot']['jobs_available'];

         echo "<br>$name $description $jobs $jobs_available";
      }

 ?>
```

Comment: I had to add ['machine'] in each of the of the variable declarations. Is there a better way to include the "machine" array in the loop